# new Date() return same value when it comes to variable

Tags: javascript, api, momentjs

I have API build by express. Then I try to create dynamic folder for storing image using multer with format : 'YYYY/MMMM/DD' and make it as variable.

```
const moment = require('moment')
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')

let x = new Date()
let yearDir = moment(x).format('YYYY')
let monthDir = moment(x).format('MMMM')
let dateDir = moment(x).format('DD')
let dynamicDir = `${yearDir}/${monthDir}/${dateDir}`

// multer storage
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (fs.existsSync(dynamicDir)) {
      console.log('upload dir is exist')
    } else {
      fs.mkdirSync(dynamicDir, {
        recursive: true
      })
      console.log('upload dir not found, creating...')
    }
    cb(null, dynamicDir)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})
let uploadFile = multer({
  storage: storage
})

module.exports = uploadFile
```

But when day changed and images uploaded, the dir for images is always constant.

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()
const uploadCtrl = require('../controllers/upload.js')
const uploadFile = require('../config/multer.js')

router.post('/upload', uploadFile.single('image'), uploadCtrl)

export default router
```

Can new Date() set to variable or I need to write them in moment like : moment(new Date()).format('DD') ?

Comment: I suspect that code is only run _once_, when your server starts up, but it's not really clear without context. Why not have a _function_ you can call?

Comment: I use multer as middleware and set destination with that (dynamicDir). What the function do you mean? @jonrsharpe

Comment: I mean... _you write_ a function. I don't know whether multer accepts a function for the destination, though. If it requires a string, maybe you can't make it dynamic.

Comment: I updated my question and attach my code, maybe you can explain what is wrong

Comment: Yes, so that code runs _once_, when you `require('../config/multer.js')`. `dynamicDir` is **not** dynamic, it's just a string. Again, why not _write a function_, then _call it_ inside the `destination` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're actually doing it the right way: there's a (slight) chance that your code will be executed at the edge of the date if you do it like this:

```
let yearDir = moment( new Date() ).format('YYYY')
let monthDir = moment( new Date() ).format('MMMM')
```

The issue that you actually have is that a module's code is always executed just once. All the subsequent imports and requires consume the result of execution. That means value of `dynamicDir`, once calculated, stays the same.

With challenges like this, there's always a rather direct solution: replace variable with a function. In this case it'll look like this (*but can be greatly simplified; scroll down if you want to see how*)

```
const getDynamicDir = () => {
  let x = new Date()
  let yearDir = moment(x).format('YYYY')
  let monthDir = moment(x).format('MMMM')
  let dateDir = moment(x).format('DD')
  return `${yearDir}/${monthDir}/${dateDir}`
}
```

... then use this function instead of variable:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const dirName = getDynamicDir();
    if (fs.existsSync(dirName)) {
      console.log('upload dir is exist')
    } else {
      fs.mkdirSync(dirName, {
        recursive: true
      })
      console.log('upload dir not found, creating...')
    }
    cb(null, dirName)
  },
```

---

Actually you don't even need this function: just use moment formatting directly:

```
const dirName = moment().format('YYYY/MMMM/DD');
```

... as it'll do exactly the same thing.